# Windows Explorer has stopped working?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have OS Windows 7 RTM. Sometimes when I click on some folders or some of partitions there's an error "Windows explorer has stopped working". Can I fix this? Does the same mistake exist on the Windows 7 full version? Thanks

Comment: The RTM *is* the full version.

Comment: Next time this happens, click the "More Information" link, and see if it gives you a DLL or EXE other than Explorer.exe.  There should be a big block of copyable text in a scrolling text box if you go far enough.  Edit your question with the pasted copy of this information and we can figure out what's causing it.

Sorry if some of the directions are incorrect.  I'm doing this from memory from a similar issue I had a while back that turned out to be caused by Stardock Fences.

Answer (score 1):

Are your partitions corrupt? Do you have any shell extensions that haven't been tested with Windows 7 installed?

RTM *is* the final version, and it's highly unlikely they'd ship with such a bug, so it must be a problem with your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Firefox in private browsing mode on Windows 7 x64 by any chance? There's a known bug in the Windows clipboard API when switching from a 32-bit application(for example, Firefox) to a 64-bit one, and it tends to cause explorer.exe to crash.

See the following bug report on FF's [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=518412)

Anyhow, it should be fixed in a future release (If you're really anxious, Firefox 3.6 beta 5 already includes the fix but being a beta release it may have other stability issues)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by one of the following issues:

- You may be using a worn or damaged video driver
- The file system on your PC may be damaged or mismatched with the other file
- You may have a virus or malware infection on your PC
- Some applications or services running on your PC can cause Windows Explorer to stop working

To solve this problem you need to determine what is causing Windows Explorer to stop working. Try the troubleshooting steps below to help determine the cause of the problem:

- Update your current video driver
- Run the system file checker (SRA) to examine the file
- Scan your PC for virus or malware infection
- Start your PC in safe mode to check the startup problem

Additional steps below are less common but still can cause Windows Explorer to stop working.

- Test your system RAM memory
- Test for image files that may contain corruption
- Perform system recovery

Comment: This looks *suspiciously* like its been copied from one of the windows knowledge base entries. Care to attribute the source with a link?