# I constantly get the error "Windows Explorer has stopped working"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Explorer has stopped working?](https://superuser.com/questions/62759/windows-explorer-has-stopped-working)

I know many have seen this before. It has been occurring so much that my PC is nearly unusable. I tried scanning the system through Command Prompt but not all of the corrupt files were fixed. Windows Explorer still fails constantly. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Could you at least post the error you're getting, if any? Also, if all else fails, just reinstall windows.

Comment: Any notable changes to PC before all this began? Hardware changes, software installed?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you think corruption is the issue, you can run disk check through command prompt. Open task manager, go to: file, run, type in **cmd**, in the new window type **chkdsk C: /F**. The flag /F will attempt to fix errors, you can also use /R to attempt to recover missing data. (chkdsk C: /F /R). ([more about disk check](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/433-disk-check.html))

And obviously, you will want to scan your harddrive. I would try Avast! and AVG, both have a free edition. Last time I used Avast, they had a boot time scan... That will probably help if your computer gives you problems during the scan.

There are definitely other antivirus' out there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Safe Mode then run both virus and spyware/malware scans to clean the system.

> I tried scanning the system through command prompt but not all the corrupt files were fixed.

Assuming you are using XP, boot to your Windows CD and run the recovery console. Then run CHKDSK C: /F to run the scan. [Here are instructions how to do that.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307654)

You may also want to run the [System File Checker](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true) to fix any corrupted files. Use the /scannow switch.

If you still can not use the PC, it is likely time to reinstall Windows.